# CAKE BAKE is returning a html output on console

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-bake

I'm just installed a brand new cake, and when i try to bake the app, this is what i get when a try to cake bake all.

if i create a new app folder from the bake, it works fine.

---

Cant find why its outputting html in my console:

```
> S:\server\htdocs\rpgcom\app>cake bake all
> 
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
>         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   <title>
>                 CakePHP: the rapid development php framework:
>                 Errors  </title>
>         <link href="S:\server\htdocs\sgen\lib\Cake\Console/favicon.ico"
> type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" /><link
> href="S:\server\htdocs\sgen\lib\Cake\Co nsole/favicon.ico"
> type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" /><link rel="stylesheet"
> type="text/css" href="S:\server\htdocs\sgen\lib\Cake\Console/css/c
> ake.generic.css" /></head> <body>
>         <div id="container">
>                 <div id="header">
>                         <h1><a href="http://cakephp.org">CakePHP: the rapid development php framework</a></h1>
>                 </div>
>                 <div id="content">
> 
> 
>                         <h2>Could not load class File</h2> <p class="error">
>         <strong>Error: </strong>
>         An Internal Error Has Occurred.</p> <h3>Stack Trace</h3> <ul class="cake-stack-trace">
>         <li><a href="#" onclick="traceToggle(event, 'file-excerpt-0')">CORE\Cake\Log\LogEngineCollection.php line 41</a>
> &rarr; <a href="#" onclick="t raceToggle(event,
> 'trace-args-0')">LogEngineCollection::_getLogger(string)</a> <div
> id="file-excerpt-0" class="cake-code-dump" style="display:none;"><
> pre><code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$enable&nbsp;=&nbsp;isset($options['enabled'])&nbsp;?&nbsp;$opt
> </span></code>]&nbsp;:&nbsp;true; </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$loggerName&nbsp;=&nbsp;$options['engine'];
> </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;unset($options['engine']);
> <span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$className&nbsp;=&nbsp;$this-&gt;_getL
> </span></code></span> </span></code></pre></div> <div
> id="trace-args-0" class="cake-code-dump" style="display:
> none;"><pre>'File'</pre></div></li>options);
>         <li><a href="#" onclick="traceToggle(event, 'file-excerpt-1')">CORE\Cake\Log\CakeLog.php line 194</a> &rarr; <a
> href="#" onclick="traceToggle( event,
> 'trace-args-1')">LogEngineCollection->load(string, array)</a> <div
> id="file-excerpt-1" class="cake-code-dump"
> style="display:none;"><pre><code> </span></code>olor:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if&nbsp;(empty(self::$_Collection))&nbsp;{
> </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;self::_init();
> </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;} <span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;self::$_Collection-&gt;load($key,&nbsp
> </span></code></span> </span></code></pre></div> <div
> id="trace-args-1" class="cake-code-dump" style="display:
> none;"><pre>'debug' array(
>         'engine' => 'File',
>         'types' => array(
>                 (int) 0 => 'notice',
>                 (int) 1 => 'info',
>                 (int) 2 => 'debug'
>         ),
>         'file' => 'debug' )</pre></div></li>
>         <li><a href="#" onclick="traceToggle(event, 'file-excerpt-2')">APP\Config\bootstrap.php line 102</a> &rarr; <a
> href="#" onclick="traceToggle(e vent,
> 'trace-args-2')">CakeLog::config(string, array)</a> <div
> id="file-excerpt-2" class="cake-code-dump"
> style="display:none;"><pre><code><span style
> ="color: #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'engine'&nbsp;=&gt;&nbsp;'File',</span></code>
> <code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'types'&nbsp;=&gt;&nbsp;array('notice',&nbsp;'info',&nbsp;'debug'),</span></code>
> <code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'file'&nbsp;=&gt;&nbsp;'debug',</span></code> <span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color:
> #000000">));</span></code></span> <code><span style="color: #000000">CakeLog::config('error',&nbsp;array(</span></code></pre></div>
> <div id="trace-args-2" class="cake-code-dump" style= "display:
> none;"><pre>'debug' array(
>         'engine' => 'File',
>         'types' => array(
>                 (int) 0 => 'notice',
>                 (int) 1 => 'info',
>                 (int) 2 => 'debug'
>         ),
>         'file' => 'debug' )</pre></div></li>
>         <li><a href="#" onclick="traceToggle(event, 'file-excerpt-3')">CORE\Cake\Core\Configure.php line 92</a> &rarr; <a
> href="#" onclick="traceToggl e(event,
> 'trace-args-3')">include(string)</a> <div id="file-excerpt-3"
> class="cake-code-dump" style="display:none;"><pre><code><span
> style="color: #00
> </span></code>bsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;);
> <code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;self::_setErrorHandlers($error,&nbsp;$excep
> </span></code> </span></code>yle="color: #000000"> <span
> class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if&nbsp;(!incl
> </span></code></span>bsp;'Config'&nbsp;.&nbsp;DS&nbsp;.&nbsp;'bootstrap.php')&nbsp;{
> <code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;trigger_error(__d('
> cake_dev',&nbsp;"Can't&nbsp;find&nbsp;application&nbsp;bootstrap&nbsp;file.&nbsp;Please&nbsp;create&nbsp;%sbootstrap.php,&nbsp;and&nbsp;make&nbsp;sure
> </span></code></pre></div> <div id="trace-args-3"
> class="cake-code-dump" style="display:
> none;"><pre>'S:\server\htdocs\rpgcom\app\Config\bootstrap.php
> '</pre></div></li>
>         <li><a href="#" onclick="traceToggle(event, 'file-excerpt-4')">CORE\Cake\bootstrap.php line 146</a> &rarr; <a
> href="#" onclick="traceToggle(ev ent,
> 'trace-args-4')">Configure::bootstrap(boolean)</a> <div
> id="file-excerpt-4" class="cake-code-dump"
> style="display:none;"><pre><code><span style="
> </span></code>">App::uses('Object',&nbsp;'Core');
> </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">App::$bootstrapping&nbsp;=&nbsp;true; </span></code>yle="color: #000000">
> </span></code></span>hlight"><code><span style="color:
> #000000">Configure::bootstrap(isset($boot)&nbsp;?&nbsp;$boot&nbsp;:&nbsp;true);
> </span></code></pre></div> <div id="trace-args-4"
> class="cake-code-dump" style="display:
> none;"><pre>true</pre></div></li>
>         <li><a href="#" onclick="traceToggle(event, 'file-excerpt-5')">CORE\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php line 131</a>
> &rarr; <a href="#" onclick=" traceToggle(event,
> 'trace-args-5')">require(string)</a> <div id="file-excerpt-5"
> class="cake-code-dump" style="display:none;"><pre><code><span style="
> color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;define('TMP',&nbsp;CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH&nbsp;.&nbsp;DS&nbsp;
> .&nbsp;'Cake'&nbsp;.&nbsp;DS&nbsp;.&nbsp;'Console'&nbsp;.&nbsp;DS&nbsp;.&nbsp;'Templates'&nbsp;.&nbsp;DS&nbsp;.&nbsp;'skel'&nbsp;.&nbsp;DS&nbsp;.&nbsp
> </span></code>nbsp;DS); </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;} <code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$boot&nbsp;=&nbsp;file_exists(ROOT&nbsp;.&nbsp;DS&nbsp;.&nbsp;APP_D
> </span></code>;DS&nbsp;.&nbsp;'Config'&nbsp;.&nbsp;DS&nbsp;.&nbsp;'bootstrap.php'); <span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;require&nbsp;CORE_PATH&nbsp;.&nbsp;'Ca
> </span></code></span>sp;.&nbsp;'bootstrap.php';
> </span></code></pre></div> <div id="trace-args-5"
> class="cake-code-dump" style="display:
> none;"><pre>'S:\server\htdocs\sgen\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php'</p
> re></div></li>
>         <li><a href="#" onclick="traceToggle(event, 'file-excerpt-6')">CORE\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php line 101</a>
> &rarr; <a href="#" onclick=" traceToggle(event,
> 'trace-args-6')">ShellDispatcher->_bootstrap()</a> <div
> id="file-excerpt-6" class="cake-code-dump"
> style="display:none;"><pre><code </span></code>color:
> #000000">&nbsp;*&nbsp;@throws&nbsp;CakeException </span></code>yle="color: #000000">&nbsp;*/ </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;protected&nbsp;function&nbsp;_initEnvironment()&nbsp;{
> <span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if&nbsp;(!$this-&gt;_bootstrap())&nbsp
> </span></code></span> <code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$message&nbsp;=&nbsp;"Unable&nbsp;to&nbsp;l
> oad&nbsp;CakePHP&nbsp;core.\nMake&nbsp;sure&nbsp;"&nbsp;.&nbsp;DS&nbsp;.&nbsp;'lib'&nbsp;.&nbsp;DS&nbsp;.&nbsp;'Cake&nbsp;exists&nbsp;in&nbsp;'&nbsp;.
> </span></code></pre></div> <div id="trace-args-6"
> class="cake-code-dump" style="display: none;"><pre></pre></div></li>
>         <li><a href="#" onclick="traceToggle(event, 'file-excerpt-7')">CORE\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php line 57</a>
> &rarr; <a href="#" onclick="t raceToggle(event,
> 'trace-args-7')">ShellDispatcher->_initEnvironment()</a> <div
> id="file-excerpt-7" class="cake-code-dump" style="display:none;"><pre>
> </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;} </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$this-&gt;parseParams($args);
> </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if&nbsp;($bootstrap)&nbsp;{
> <span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$this-&gt;_ini
> </span></code></span> </span></code></pre></div> <div
> id="trace-args-7" class="cake-code-dump" style="display:
> none;"><pre></pre></div></li>
>         <li><a href="#" onclick="traceToggle(event, 'file-excerpt-8')">CORE\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php line 68</a>
> &rarr; <a href="#" onclick="t raceToggle(event,
> 'trace-args-8')">ShellDispatcher->__construct(array)</a> <div
> id="file-excerpt-8" class="cake-code-dump" style="display:none;"><pre>
> </span></code>yle="color: #000000">&nbsp;*&nbsp;@return&nbsp;void
> </span></code>yle="color: #000000">&nbsp;*/ </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;public&nbsp;static&nbsp;function&nbsp;run($argv)&nbsp;{
> <span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$dispatcher&nbsp;=&nbsp;new&nbsp;Shell
> </span></code></span> <code><span style="color:
> #000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$dispatcher-&gt;_stop($dispatcher-&gt;dispatch()&nbsp;===&nbsp;fals
> </span></code></pre></div> <div id="trace-args-8"
> class="cake-code-dump" style="display: none;"><pre>array(
>         (int) 0 => 'S:\server\htdocs\sgen\lib\Cake\Console\cake.php',
>         (int) 1 => '-working',
>         (int) 2 => 'S:\server\htdocs\rpgcom\app ',
>         (int) 3 => 'bake',
>         (int) 4 => 'all' )</pre></div></li>
>         <li><a href="#" onclick="traceToggle(event, 'file-excerpt-9')">CORE\Cake\Console\cake.php line 43</a> &rarr; <a
> href="#" onclick="traceToggle( event,
> 'trace-args-9')">ShellDispatcher::run(array)</a> <div
> id="file-excerpt-9" class="cake-code-dump"
> style="display:none;"><pre><code><span style=" </span></code>">
> </span></code>yle="color:
> #000000">unset($paths,&nbsp;$path,&nbsp;$found,&nbsp;$dispatcher,&nbsp;$root,&nbsp;$ds);
> </span></code>yle="color: #000000">
> </span></code></span>hlight"><code><span style="color:
> #000000">return&nbsp;ShellDispatcher::run($argv); <code><span style="color: #000000"></span></code></pre></div> <div
> id="trace-args-9" class="cake-code-dump" style="display:
> none;"><pre>array(
>         (int) 0 => 'S:\server\htdocs\sgen\lib\Cake\Console\cake.php',
>         (int) 1 => '-working',
>         (int) 2 => 'S:\server\htdocs\rpgcom\app ',
>         (int) 3 => 'bake',
>         (int) 4 => 'all' )</pre></div></li> </ul> <script type="text/javascript"> function traceToggle(event, id) {
>         var el = document.getElementById(id);
>         el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
>         event.preventDefault();
>         return false; } </script>
>                 </div>
>                 <div id="footer">
>                         <a href="http://www.cakephp.org/" target="_blank"><img
> src="S:\server\htdocs\sgen\lib\Cake\Console/img/cake.power.gif"
> alt="Ca kePHP: the rapid development php framework" border="0" /></a> 
> </div>
>         </div>
>         </body> </html>
> 
> 
> S:\server\htdocs\rpgcom\app>
```

Can Anyone try to help-me, this is an new installed and up to date cake revision.

Comment: What do you mean by `if i create a new app folder from the bake, it works fine.`?

Comment: Let me guess: You are trying to create a model "File" for a table "files"? File is not allowed as there is already such a class (Utility). PS: Upgrade to current 2.4 master. The HTML issues should be resolved there.

Comment: Other way to express it is: "I'm getting a `Could not load class File` error".

Answer (score 0):

Bake will output html in case of an error. I can see that you have restricted class in your project ("File"). You propably have 'files' table, rename this table and your problem should go away.

See all restricted classes in [API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/) and avoid them in your project.